# Visual Studio 2022 17.3.6 can't create local git repository while offline

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

After I updated Visual Studio 2022 from 17.0 to 17.3.6 it can no longer create local git repository with error "An error occurred while sending the request.". I saw some solutions on internet like adding solution folder to trusted and running VS as admin, but it didn't worked.

Now I tried it on other PC with internet access (my PC doesn't have internet connection). And with internet disconnected it gave same error but with connection to internet it worked.

Are there any solution to this problem?

Comment: I guess it is probably trying to push something up to a remote repository - but the simple solution would simply be to create the local repository _outside of Visual Studio_ (using a command line or other tool).